# Nuxt Content query related articles

Tags: nuxt.js, blogs, hugo

I'm migrating a blog from Hugo to Nuxt (using Nuxt Content) and I could'nt replicate [hugo's built-in related content](https://gohugo.io/content-management/related/) lists. Basically, I need to list related articles on each article page based on similar tags (get the 3 most similar articles based on the number of common tags). Is it possible? Thanks.

Comment: There is nothing baked-in like that IMO but you could probably achieve the same result by filtering according fields. What did you tried so far?

Comment: I thought of exposing tags to the navigation object, then iterate through all other articles to get an object with each article and common tags... The problem is how it scales with new articles...

Comment: `surround` may help for the latter: https://content.nuxtjs.org/v1/getting-started/fetching#surroundslugorpath-options